# Seeking QGIS plugin for creating buildings?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, software-recommendations, 3d

is there a plugin for QGIS, which extrudes buildings with sort of random heights and adds a roof on top?

Ideally, the plugin would also put different textures as facades, e.g., having some templates for a small village v a large city.

I'm looking for something comparable to ESRI CityEngine for QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this stage putting textures on buildings is maybe asking too much to QGIS (rather export your data to a dedicated 3D Modeler ?) but you can try **the 2.5D Renderer style** that is internally provided by QGIS since version 2.14.
You only need to provide the **building height** in one of your attribute table columns.
See [Experiments in the 3rd dimension](https://anitagraser.com/2016/02/14/experiments-in-the-3rd-dimension/) By Anita Graser.